# Key Events in ASP

Tags: asp.net, keyboard

How can I capture key events in ASP using C# code?

for example, I want to press the left key and a text box will pronounce "Left Pressed".

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstand how web applications and ASP.NET work. Keys are pressed by the user on the client side, in the browser that shows HTML pages. ASP.NET and the C# code that makes up the web application run on the server side. You cannot really capture key events on the server side. Even if you could, you shouldn't - every time the user would press a key, you'd have to send it over to the server side, evaluate it and then render the page again and send it back to the browser. This would generate a lot of traffic and force page reloads very frequently, making the pages very hard to use. Even AJAX calls wouldn't help much with this.

Instead, you should handle key presses on the client side, in JavaScript code that runs inside the browser and when you encounter something that the server needs to handle, you can then perform a server call.

This site (among a bunch of others) has code samples that show how to implement key detection in JavaScript:

http://www.alessandrolacava.com/using-javascript-to-detect-the-key-pressed/

**Edit**:

Alternatively, you can try using Silverlight, which is a programmable browser plugin similar to Flash. Silverlight hosts the .NET Framework and can be programmed using C#. Even in this case, though, you'll handle keys on the client side, not on the server.

Comment: thanks but this quite disappointing since I made a tetris game in c# and I want to translate it to ASP with C#, writing the whole thing in Javascript doesnt sound like a good idea. there must be a way to use keys in server side, maybe with imported controls?

Comment: @DrorR Even if you manage to make that work, that'd be a terrible idea. As I said, key presses happen on the client - there's no reason to send those to the server, especially in the case of a game like Tetris. All that'd do is generate network traffic and server load.  I updated my answer about Silverlight.